# Why must we prove the uniqueness of Taylor polynomials we can easily achieve through differentiation?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In most calculus courses, we encounter the uniqueness theorem for Taylor polynomials, stating that if $Q_n$ is a polynomial which satisfies $|f(x)-Q_n(x)|\leq C|x-a|^{n+1}$, then $Q_n(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$.

This allows us to prove that certain series expansion are indeed the Taylor series for functions which are otherwise cumbersome to differentiate.

Some functions which are "easily differentiable" involve $e^x,\sin{x},\cos{x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}$. Thus, we should be able to simply use the original Taylor series formula to prove the Taylor series of these expansions, and no uniqueness theorem should be needed.

However, in all caclulus textbooks I've encountered, in proving the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$, they apply the geometric sum formula, then use uniqueness. Why do this when we can just easily prove the nth derivative using induction, and thus prove the expansion using Taylors formula? I get why we must use uniqueness when for example using the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to prove the Taylor series for say $\ln(1+x)$ or $\arctan{x}$, as we need to involve composite series and differentiation/integration.

As an example, a rigorous proof for the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ was given using the uniqueness formula, but the Taylor series for $(1+x)^{\alpha}$ was simply derived by induction (perhaps we can use induction to prove the nth derivative to then use the Lagrange remainder?)

For what functions do we have to use the uniqueness theorem as opposed to using Taylors formula directly (given that the nth derivative can be proven using induction)? And are both methods "rigorous enough"?

Comment: Can it not be useful, in a teaching context, to utilize the power of a uniqueness theorem in a context that is basic enough to understand what's going on?

Comment: Never heard of this approach.

Comment: In the question, there are leading uses of the terms _must_ and _have to_ (signifying _necessity_) that do not seem logically correct. Instead, it _suffices_ to use some technique, or _we may_ use some technique. <> In some ways, mathematics is analogous to hiking: There may be multiple trails to a given destination, some easier or more laborious than others, with _easier_ dependent on context, such as _where have we reached so far_? As Arthur notes, there can be value in following multiple trails; that's how we learn the structure of the landscape, or try out new climbing techniques.